# Expected value and variance of arithmetic mean of random variables

Tags: self-study, variance, expected-value

The question is

> Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be drawn iid from $Beta(0.1,0.5)$. Let $\bar{X} = \frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{i=1} X_i$.
>
> a) Derive $\mathbb{E}(\bar{X})$ and $\mathbb{V}(\bar{X})$

I know how to get the expectation and variance of a random variable from a given distribution. But I'm not how to get the expectation and variance of $\bar{X}%$. Not sure where to being actually.

Comment: What rules do you know that might enable you to compute the expectation and variance of a sum of random variables or a constant multiple of a random variable?  (You can look up the expectation and variance of a Beta distribution: Wikipedia lists them, for example.)

Comment: So I can change $\mathbb{E}(\bar{X})$ to $\sum^n_{i=1}\mathbb{E}(\bar{X_i})$, which I can calculate since I know the expected value of a single random variable from the Beta distribution.

Similarly for the variance, I can do: $\mathbb{V}(\bar{X}) = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum^n_{i=1}{\mathbb{V}(X_i)}$

Comment: Yes, that is correct: it called the "linearity of expectation."  Variances enjoy a comparable relationship with linear combinations, although a little more complicated, but the same idea will serve you in good stead.  (I see you have just edited your comment to include the variance rule; I'm glad you correctly converted the $\frac{1}{n}$ to $\frac{1}{n^2}$.)

Comment: When you obtain an answer you're confident is correct, please post it as a reply here so we have it for the record. :-)

Comment: So I got $\mathbb{E}(\bar{X}) = \frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{i=1}{\mathbb{E}(X_i)} = \frac{1}{n}n\frac{0.1}{0.1+0.5} = \frac{1}{6} $

and $\mathbb{V}(\bar{X}) = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum^n_{i=1}{\mathbb{V}(X_i)} = \frac{1}{n^2}n\frac{0.1*0.5}{(0.1+0.5)^2(0.1+0.5+1)} = \frac{1}{n}\frac{0.05}{(0.36)(1.6)}$

Answer (score 5):

I got the same answer as you.  However, be aware of the following:

$
\mathbb{V}(X + Y) = \mathbb{V}(X) + \mathbb{V}(Y) + 2\text{COV}(X,Y)
$

For a long summation of variances, like the one you did, it becomes:

$
\mathbb{V}(\sum^n_{i=1}X_i)=\sum^n_{i=1}\sum^n_{j=1}\text{COV}(X_i,X_j)
$

This is the "more complicated" part that [whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber) mentioned :-). Make sure you understand what happens to the covariances and why.  Let me know if you need help there.

Comment: Yea, I saw that and thought the covariance term was 0 because the random variables were drawn iid.

Comment: The formula for the variance of $X+Y$ is wrong.  It should be $$\mathbb V(X+Y) = \mathbb V(X) + \mathbb V(Y) + 2\text{COV}(X, Y).$$

Comment: John you're correct, that's exactly why it is 0.  Dilip thanks for catching the typo, will fix it now.